# Removing computer name from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Right now, this is what my Terminal shows:

```
MyName's-MacBookPro:location MyName$
```

I'd like for it to only show my name, so something like this:

```
MyName$
```

When I browsed online for a solution, they said to edit my `.bashrc` file. I added the following line to my `.bashrc`:

```
export PS1="\u$ "
```

but there hasn't been any change, even after restarting Terminal.

This is the current contents of my `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PS1="\u$ "
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two easy options:

- Move your changes from `.bashrc` to `.bash_profile` (and delete `.bashrc`)
- Add a line `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile` to make sure `.bashrc` is read during shell startup

Comment: While this will work, I'd suggest putting `source ~/.bashrc` into `.bash_profile` and then using `.bashrc` as normal. Don't know why the Bash shipped with OSX doesn't read `.bashrc` itself.

Comment: Apple will undoubtedly replace bash in the next few years anyway since they will never use the latest GPLv3 version of bash (they don't use anything licensed under GPLv3). There hasn't been much innovation or improvement in OS X's bash in a very long time.

Comment: Zsh is completely up to date on OS X though, and has some interesting features. I'd personally recommend that anyone bored with their shell should look into it. Plus: http://ohmyz.sh

Comment: @DavidLord because the terminal running a shell is the first time OS X runs a shell and so should be a login shell (Under X11 the login shell runs and starts X11 and so the terminal are run as subshells of the login shell - I wonder if systemd use  will chnage this)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked!

@DavidLord, what exactly do you mean by "putting `source ~/.bashrc` into `.bash_profile`"? This sounds like a better way to do it.

Comment: Haha @WilliamTFroggard you were right, macOS Catalina will replace bash with zsh by default.

Comment: @saadq I had forgotten I said that. Neat.