# Change Mac terminal name after the @ symbol

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I just bought the new Mac mini, this is my first owned Mac. I decided to use the terminal and it shows my name but also my girlfriends name after the @ symbol. I don't know how this happened and what I can do to change it (harrisonokojie@Aminas-Air) I need to change the @Aminas-Air

Comment: Check the computer name in System Preferences -> Sharing. If it's correct there, your computer is probably inheriting that name from a previous computer that happened to have the same IP address, via the local DNS server. See ["OS X computer name not matching what shows on terminal"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal).

Comment: @GordonDavisson it says Harrison there , how do I override it and change the name to show my name on my new Mac

Comment: Try changing it in System Preferences, then restart and see if the change gets picked up in the hostname it displays in Terminal. If it doesn't, you might need to use the `scutil` override (see the other Q&A I linked). Or just ignore it; it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

- Animas-Air is your local hostname. Read Apple Support: [Change your computer’s name or local hostname on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-computers-local-hostname-mac-mchlp2322/mac)
- If you want to change PROMPT (or PS1), you might some ideas in [Removing computer name from terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192730/removing-computer-name-from-terminal?rq=1)